# Помогите зафиксить ошибку "postgres error SQLSTATE 26000"

Tags: postgresql

Проблема в следующем:

```
SELECT id,
          planned_servers,
           country_id,
           traffic_manager_active,
           proxy_id,
           execution_date,
           status,
           created_at,
           updated_at,
           deleted_at
    FROM schedules
    WHERE execution_date <= now()
      AND status = $1
      AND deleted_at IS NULL
```

при попытке выполнить вышеописанный селект из базы данных, бд возвращает ошибку "ERROR: prepared statement "lrupsc_1_0" does not exist (SQLSTATE 26000)"

данная ошибка начала появлятся после обновления версии постгрес на сервере

В качестве ЯП используется Go
для работы с постгрес библиотека https://github.com/jackc/pgx

Comment: а это точно не в каком-либо ЯП написано? Потому что тут не видно никакого `lrupsc_1_0`

Comment: pgbouncer между приложением и базой есть? Если да, то какой режим pool_mode?

Comment: @Мелкий pgbouncer не установлен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за совет, на деле так и оказалось, библиотека которую я использовал https://github.com/jackc/pgx под капотом кеширует у себя prepared statements после чего использует их во время обращения к базе
Получилась ситуация в которой драйвер локально у себя закешировал запросы, а бд постоянно перезагружает конекшн и об этих запросах очень быстро забывает)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что по умолчанию https://github.com/jackc/pgx кеширует подготовленные выражения и пытается потом вызывать их на уровне постгрес
Постгрес же постоянно обновляет конекшн (а хранит подготовленные выражения только в рамках одного конекшна)
Вот и получилась ситуация в которой драйвер все еще хранит prep statement, а в базе его нет.

Решение:

использовать SimpleProtocol при подключении к базе

```
func OpenPGX(pgConnString string) (*pgx.Conn, error) {
    connConfig, err := pgx.ParseConfig(pgConnString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    connConfig.PreferSimpleProtocol = true // disable prepared statements caching by default
    return pgx.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), connConfig)
}
```

Comment: `Постгрес же постоянно обновляет конекшн` - если только по пути нет какого-то другого пула коннектов - то это тоже делает клиентская библиотека. Одно соединение postgresql может жить неограниченно долго и честно хранить все prepared statements о которых просили (и о которых не просили забыть через вызовы DEALLOCATE или DISCARD ALL).